# Values not getting added in the global ArrayList in java

Tags: java, algorithm, backtracking

I'm solving [this](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/subset/) problem on interviewbit and logically I've solved it using backtracking but I'm not able to add values in the `ArraList` which I defined outside main function. My code looks something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
class main {
    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> solution = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> subsets(ArrayList<Integer> A) {
        if(A.size() == 0){
            return new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        }
        Collections.sort(A);

        ArrayList<Integer> subset = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        solution.add(subset);
        subsetsUtil(A, subset, 0);
        return solution;
    }

    public static void subsetsUtil(ArrayList<Integer> A, ArrayList<Integer> subset, int index) {
        for(int i=index; i<A.size(); i++) {
            //including the element
            subset.add(A.get(i));
            solution.add(subset);
            subsetsUtil(A, subset, i+1);
            //excluding the element
            subset.remove(subset.size() - 1);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = input.nextInt();

        ArrayList<Integer> A = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            A.add(i + 1);
        }
        System.out.println(subsets(A));
    }
}
```

Here I've declared the `solution` as an arrayList outside all the functions but whenever I'm adding an array list to this list. It is not getting added. For input = 3, the solution is `[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]` which should be something like this :

```
[]
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3]
[2]
[2, 3]
[3]
```

But if I print the subset values in subsetUtils function, it is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the subset lists you add to the solution are the same instance. Which is gradually getting mutated until it has no elements.

change:

```
solution.add(subset);
```

to:

```
solution.add(new ArrayList<>(subset));
```